Pantheon updates show success, but modules still outdated in admin interface. Any idea why?
I used the Pantheon Dashboard to run updates to my Drupal 10 site. It reported that all updates ran successfully. And yet, when I go to my Drupal site's module update page (/admin/modules/update), I still see modules that have updates. For example, Linkit, shown here in my Drupal site as version 6.1.4:

Here's the line in the composer require section:
"drupal/linkit": "^6.1.4",

Shouldn't that pick up any new updates?
Additionally, Pantheon's commit log is reporting that it updated Linkit from 6.1.5 to 6.1.6:

What's going on here?

This seems like a question for Pantheon support.  Pantheon dashboard is a proprietary tool and only Pantheon staff can check the logs, so anything people say here would just be a wild guess.

Finding out who's "lying" might be the best first step - run drush eval "print \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getExtensionInfo('linkit')['version'];" against the site; if it says 6.1.4 then Pantheon's update didn't work, if it says 6.1.6, you probably have a caching issue. Clear the caches (potentially including redis) and check again. If it's the latter, it might be worth contacting Pantheon anyway to ask if they know why this cache isn't getting rebuilt following their update
